# Task not serializable: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code snippet which I'm trying to execute and which works fine in one case and fails in another case. Below are the PASS and FAIL cases.

```
def execute(events: DataFrame, metaAttributes: List[String], name: String, version: String, refreshVersion: String): DataFrame = {

val modelConfig = getModelConfig(modelName, modelVersion, modelRefreshVersion)
val model = getModel(modelConfig)

val modelAttributes = metaAttributes ::: model.getAttributes.toList
val modelSchema = createSchema(modelAttributes)
val modelEncoder = RowEncoder(modelSchema)

var resultAttributes = metaAttributes
resultAttributes =  resultAttributes :+ "percentile"
resultAttributes =  resultAttributes :+ "probabilityScore"
val schema = createSchema(resultAttributes)
val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)

val finalEventsDF = events.mapPartitions(iterator => {
  iterator.map(event => {
    val modelResultRow = ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
    modelAttributes.foreach(modelAttribute => {
      try {
        modelResultRow += event.getAs(modelAttribute).toString
      }
      catch {
        case e: Exception => modelResultRow += null
      }
    })
    RowFactory.create(modelResultRow: _*)
  })
})(modelEncoder)

finalEventsDF
```

}

Another scoring method, this method is being called in both the cases I mean for both fail and pass. It's a common method for both cases.

````
    val resultRow = ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
    val scoringResult = score(model, event)
    for (index <- 0 until metaAttributes.length) {
      try {
        resultRow += event.get(index).toString
      }
      catch {
        case e: Exception => resultRow += null
      }
    }
    resultRow += scoringResult.getPercentile.toString
    resultRow += scoringResult.getScoreDetails.toString
    RowFactory.create(resultRow: _*)
  } ```

Now, With this, I see some conflicting/strange behavior from code itself in which one case is working fine and same is failing if calls second method in loop. 

**Case 1:** If I execute the below lines then my code runs fine and returns the expected output

```**val event = finalEventsDF.first()**
   val row = scoreModelRequest(model, event, metaAttributes)```

**Case 2:** If the same case I execute in the loop then it starts failing with exception as below

```val scoringResultDF = finalEventsDF.map(event =>
      **scoreModelRequest(model, event, metaAttributes)**
    )(encoder)
````

Exception with stack trace :

````
Task not serializable
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:850)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:608)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2489)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.first(Dataset.scala:2503)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.org.link.score.model.pbp.TestModel
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.org.link.score.model.pbp.TestModel, value: TestModel4090_1.7_v20230321suspect)
    - field (class: scala.runtime.ObjectRef, name: elem, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.runtime.ObjectRef, TestModel4090_1.7_v20230321suspect)
    - field (class: com.org.link.score.decision.service.ModelService$$anonfun$1, name: model$1, type: class scala.runtime.ObjectRef)
    - object (class com.org.link.score.decision.service.ModelService$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, name: func, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec, MapPartitions <function1>, obj#1379: org.apache.spark.sql.Row```

Can someone please help me with suggestions so that I can figure out the mistake I'm doing this code? 

Thanks for the help in advance!
````

Comment: I recommend reading about what "task not serializable" means in Spark context, there are plenty of articles explaining it. Then if you really struggle, quick tip: put everything in a `object`, comment stuff until that works to identify the specific thing which is not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided, says you are trying to run transformations on a not serializable object named `TestModel`.

Spark requires that all functions and data used within a transformation or action must be serializable.

To solve your issue, you need to implement **Serializable Interface** like this:

```scala
class TestModel extends Serializable {
}
```